# FPGA, DDR3 Layout

Tags: fpga, ram

In my new project I use a FPGA to load some data into a [DDR3 RAM](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Micron/MT41K64M16TW-107-AUTJ/?qs=rrS6PyfT74caRuiV%252BzwQNA%3D%3D).

Can I directly connect the I/Os of the RAM with the I/Os of the FPGA? Or do I passive components in between them?

Comment: Which FPGA in particular? What IO standards and termination does it support? Is there an application note from the vendor discussing this? (I know that Xilinx had a wealth of information on connecting their Virtex-5 FPGAs to DDR2 DRAMs, but not sure about newer models)

Comment: @nanofarad lots of application notes, data sheets, eval boards …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FPGA vendors have extensive app notes for this. I encourage you to study these in detail so you understand the problems and solutions for DRAM signal integrity.

That said, what approach you take depends on the performance you seek, and how many DRAMS you have connected.

If you have a single device, and are not aiming for the very highest clock speed, you can connect the device directly. You can adjust the drive strength of the DQ and control/address buses to get a rough impedance match. This would be a DDR1-grade approach.

As the speeds get higher, you may consider using series termination for control / address to get better matching. This would be a DDR2 grade approach.

For multiple devices and or higher speeds, you should consider using Vtt termination for control / address and use ‘fly-by’ routing, which DDR3 supports.

Finally, if you intend to use SODIMM, you need to use Vtt.

For all of these, you connect DQ directly, as both the DRAM and the controller have on-die termination. Give priority to DQ in your routing, and use lower impedance (50 ohm) if you can.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on your FPGA… these days usually it's point-to-point, rarely you need series termination. There is a whole book (or more!) in the FPGA manuals for the memory controller interfaces. The evaluation board schematic also is useful: you will need to supply vrefs and stuff to make it work.

IMHO if you are even asking this question good luck on having a good layout for the signal lines. It's horribly critical for DDR memories.